# Is lat/long really required for ALL values with MetaData_UserMetaDataValue_Set (buddy.com)

Tags: geocoding

I'm using buddy.com and the docs for `MetaData_UserMetaDataValue_Set` say:

> string    MetaLatitude
>   - The latitude of the MetaData location, this value must be a valid FLOAT. All MetaData is > tagged with a location which can then be used to search API calls
>
> string    MetaLongitude
>   - The Longitude of the MetaData location, this value must be a valid FLOAT. All MetaData is > tagged with a location which can then be used to search API calls

I need to store metadata for users where it does not make sense to have location data.

1. Do I have to store a long/lat?
2. If not, what do I pass for MetaLong/Latitude?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did this question get down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes all of the metadata is location based by design, the Latitude and Longitude need to be real values even if they are not used.

If you don't need to use the location data, simply use a hard-coded and valid Lat/Long for all the records.

For example you could always pass in Latitude = 47.675272 and Longitude = -122.20624 , this is a valid Lat/Long and points to a location in Kirkland, WA.